# How to Sort, Index, Random generate Sequence of Number from a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate random number between the list like start year is 1950, and end year is 1960, the formula I'm trying is

```
=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN($D$3,$D$4),'SP500 Returns2'!$A$3:$F$103,2,0)
```

I also tried this formula

```
=if($D$3 < $D$4, $D$3 + Randombetween(1,10),"")
```

but it gives me only the value up to the condition true and show me only 2 or 3 values but I need complete value between 1950-1960 but with different sequence every time I open the workbook or when the sheet is changed.

I have also a button of random generate that will populate the column B only from the value column A, I want a formula / function / VBA code that could generate a series between the selective numbers as I discuss above.

Here is overlook of my sheet.

[image]
How to add formula in Column A that should generate range between the selection of years? I also tried this formula

```
=Randombetween($D$3,$D$4) but it return duplicate values.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this sub:

```
Sub GenerateRandomYearsBetween()
    Dim myYear As Long, i As Long
    Dim years As New Collection

    For myYear = Range("D3") To Range("D4")
        years.Add myYear
    Next

    For myYear = 1 To years.Count
        i = Int((years.Count) * Rnd + 1)
        Range("A8").Offset(myYear).Value = years(i)
        years.Remove i
    Next
End Sub
```

which you may call form the relevant event handler

---

**OR** you could use its corresponding `Function()`:

```
Function GenerateRandomYearsBetween(startYear As Variant, endyear As Variant) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim myYear As Long, i As Long
    Dim initialYears As New Collection
    ReDim finalYears(1 To endyear - startYear + 1) As Long

    For myYear = startYear To endyear
        initialYears.Add myYear
    Next

    For myYear = 1 To initialYears.Count
        i = Int((initialYears.Count) * Rnd + 1)
        finalYears(myYear) = initialYears(i)
        initialYears.Remove i
    Next

    GenerateRandomYearsBetween = finalYears
End Function
```

which you would place as "array formula" in the ***proper number of cells*** (i.e. as many cells as the number of years between the referenced ones) as

```
=GenerateRandomYearsBetween($D$3;$D$4)
```